# Avoid subscribing in Angular Service using RxJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am working on an angular project that needs to load up pages and then display them one by one / two by two.

As per [this article](https://indepth.dev/posts/1279/rxjs-in-angular-when-to-subscribe-rarely#:%7E:text=So%20far%20as%20I%20can%20tell%2C%20you%20never%20have%20to%20subscribe%20to%20Observables%20inside%20services.) and some other sources, subscribing in services is almost never necessary. So is there a way to rewrite this in pure reactive style using RxJS operators?

Here's what I have (simplified) :

```
export class NavigationService {

  private pages: Page[] = [];
  private mode = Mode.SinglePage;

  private index = 0;
  private currentPages = new BehaviorSubject<Page[]>([]);
  
  constructor(
    private pageService: PageService,
    private view: ViewService,
  ) {
    this.pageService.pages$.subscribe(pages => {
      this.setPages(pages);
    });

    this.view.mode$.subscribe(mode => {
      this.setMode(mode);
    });
  }

  private setPages(pages: Page[]) {
    this.pages = pages;
    this.updateCurrentPages();
  }

  private setMode(mode: Mode) {
    this.mode = mode;
    this.updateCurrentPages();
  }

  private updateCurrentPages() {
    // get an array of current pages depending on pages array, mode & index
    this.currentPages.next(...);
  }

  public goToNextPage() {
    this.index += 1;
    this.updateCurrentPages();
  }

  public get currentPages$() {
    return this.currentPages.asObservable();
  }
}
```

I've tried multiple solutions and didn't manage to get it right. The closest I got was using `scan()`, but it always reset my accumulated value when the outer observables (pages, mode) got updated.

Any help is appreciated, thanks !

Comment: May I know why you want to get rid of `subscribe()`?

Comment: @BadPiggie [this article](https://indepth.dev/posts/1279/rxjs-in-angular-when-to-subscribe-rarely#:~:text=So%20far%20as%20I%20can%20tell%2C%20you%20never%20have%20to%20subscribe%20to%20Observables%20inside%20services.) as well as many more sources that say that it's not necessary. I edited the question to contain that info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **merge** to create reducer functions from observables.  These functions will update part of a state maintained by the service.  They are past along to the **scan** operator which will update the prior state from the reducer.  After the reducer is run, *currentPages* is set on the new state and that new state is returned.

```
export class NavigationService {

  private readonly relativePageChangeSubject = new Subject<number>();

  readonly state$ = merge(
    this.pageService.pages$.pipe(map((pages) => (vm) => ({ ...vm, pages }))),
    this.relativePageChangeSubject.pipe(map((rel) => (vm) => ({ ...vm, index: vm.index + rel }))),
    this.view.mode$.pipe(map((mode) => (vm) => ({ ...vm, mode })))
  ).pipe(
    startWith((s) => s), // if necessary, force an initial value to be emitted from the initial value in scan.
    scan((s, reducer) => {
      const next = reducer(s);
      // update currentPages on the next state here.
      return next;
    }, { currentPages: [], index: 0, mode: Mode.SinglePage, pages: [] }),
    shareReplay(1)
  )

  readonly currentPages$ = this.state$.pipe(
    map(x => x.currentPages),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );

  constructor(private pageService: PageService, private view: ViewService) { }

  goToNextPage() {
    this.relativePageChangeSubject.next(1);
  }
}
```

Notes:

- Instead of having a nextPage Subject, a more flexible relative change subject is used that will modify the index from the value in the prior state.
- The *currentPage$* observable isn't necessary, as a consumer could just attach to the main *state$* and map as needed.  Feel free to make *state$* private or remove *currentPage$*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's very helpful. I just want to ask if writing it this way is really worth it? In my opinion this is much more complex to understand than what I wrote in the question. I mean I understand the code but things get more complicated in real apps because I use objects. The reducer pattern to me seems to be more function oriented. I know that this way is more correct, but is this used in real cases?

Comment: You're right for somebody else coming in new it needs some explaining, and it can certainly be overkill.  Personally, I use this a lot, especially in angular components where I tie all observables into a single model.  For me it handles the complication when several events can be happening at overlapping intervals and they effect the same properties.  I do it so much that it's become second nature, so even in situations where it isn't necessary I end up doing it because I'm used to seeing the pattern.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Last question, is method valid while using objects? For example I am encapsulating the pages into a collection class, also encapsulating it's traversal in an iterator class, etc. From what I've read/seen, RxJS is more oriented towards functional programming. Would you still use this if your app is heavily leaning towards an OOP design? And if not, do you have other recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Let's first detail what you are doing:

- You subscribe to `pageService.pages$` and `view.mode$`
- Those subscriptions take the values and put them in a private variabkle
- Then fire a function to use those two variables
- Finally, trigger a value push.

All this can be done in a simple pipeline. You'd need to include the index as an observable (behaviour subject in our case) to react to that change too.

Use combineLatest, this will subscribe to all observables we want, and trigger the pipe WHEN ALL have fired once, and every time one changes afterwards. You may want to use `.pipe(startWith("something"))` on observables that should have a default value so your observable pipe triggers asap.

CombineLatest will then provide an object as value, with each value in the object key passed when created. Here pages, mode and index. I've used a switchMap to demo here if updateCurrentPages passes an observable, but you could use a map if there is no async task to be done.

```
 export class NavigationService {

  readonly currentPages$:Observable<Pages[]>;
  
  constructor(
    private pageService: PageService,
    private view: ViewService,
  ) {
     this.paginator = new Paginator(this.pageService.pages$);
     this.currentPages$ = combineLatest({
          pages:this.pageService.pages$,
          mode:this.view.mode$,
          index:this.this.paginator.pageChange$
     }).pipe(
        switchMap(({pages,mode,index})=>{
           return this.updateCurrentPages(pages,mode);
         }),
     );
     
  }

  
  private updateCurrentPages() {
    // get an array of current pages depending on pages array, mode & index
    this.currentPages.next(...);
  }

  public goToNextPage() {
    this.paginator.next();
  }

}

class Paginator{
    pageChange$ = combineLatest({
        total:this.pages$.pipe(map(pages=>pages.length)),
        wanted:this.pageMove$}).pipe(map({total,wanted}=>{
            // Make sure it is between 0 and maximum according to pages.
            return Math.max(Math.min(total-1,wanted),0);
        }),
        // Do not emit twice the same page (pressing next when already at last)
        dinstinctUntilChanged());
    );
    pageMove$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
    constructor(pages$: Observable<Pages[]>){

    }
    next(){
        this.pageMove$.next(this.pageMove$.value()+1);
    }
    previous(){
        this.pageMove$.next(this.pageMove$.value()-1);
    }
    to(i:number){
        this.pageMove$.next(i);
    }
}
```

Beware tough about stating that `subscribe` is never needed. You may want to subscribe to some events for some reason. It is just that combining everything in a pipeline makes things easier to handle... In the example above, the observables will be unsubscribed to when the consumer of your service unsubscribes to currentPages$. So one thing less to handle.

Also, note that if multiple consumers subscribe to this service's currentPages$ the pipeline will be duplicated and unecessary work will be done, once for each subscriber. While this MAY be good, you might want to have everyone subscribe to the same "final" observable. This is easily do-able by adding share() or shareReplay(1) at the end of your pipeline. Share will make sure the same observable pipeline will be used for the new subscriber, and they will receive new values starting from then. Using shareReplay(1), will do the same but also emit the latest value directly on subscribe (just like BehaviourSubject) the 1 as parameter is indeed the number of replays to send out...

Hope this helps! When you master the RxJS you'll see that things will get easier and easier (see the difference in code amount!) but getting the hang of it take a little bit of time. Do not worry, just perseverate you'll get there. (Hint to get better, using outside variables/properties are the evil of handling pipelines)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's helpful! However, how would you adapt this if you had to use the value of the `pages` observable for calculating the index? For example to check if you're on the last page?

Comment: Just like you would do normally... You receive the 3 variables now. Ah, I saw I had forgot to put index in the switchMap...

Comment: what I meant is, the function `goToNextPage()` can't do this.index.next(...), without checking if the new value is `< pages.length`. And seeing as pages$ is an observable, you'd be forced to do for example `firstValueFrom()`. I should have mentioned this in my question

Comment: Then I'd recommend using a Paginator to keep the pagination logic contained. Pass it the pages observable so it acts accordingly. It will have 3 methods, one for next, previous and to. Allowing to go up one page, down one page or to an arbitrary page. This will trigger an observable with the requested page, it will then be restrained to the possible pages. You can then use that observable to be able to react on the page change knowing it will be constrained correctly. Also, we add distinctUntilChanged so the paginator does not send twice the same page index to prevent working for nothing.